# Bitmap outside array bounds

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I have the following code:

```
if (source != null)
        {
            int count = 0;

            int stride = (source.PixelWidth * source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
            byte[] pixels = new byte[source.PixelHeight * stride];
            source.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

            for (int y = 0; y < source.PixelHeight; y = y + 2)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < source.PixelWidth; x = x + 2)
                {
                    int index = y * stride + 4 * x;
                    count = index;

                    byte red = pixels[index];
                    byte green = pixels[index + 1];
                    byte blue = pixels[index + 2];
                    byte alpha = pixels[index + 3];
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Array Length, pixels: " + pixels.Count() + "," + count);
        }
```

However, i am having an issue where certain bitmap images, when stepped through throw an exception

"System.IndexOutOfRangeException" as the index passes the pixel [ ] array count, does anyone know how to solve this efficiently without oversizing the array?

I want to display the progress as i go along hence the need for an accurate array :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you debug and figure out where and how it breaks?

Comment: i have tried, it works for some images, but others, the index falls outside the bounds, hence why i'm asking for help.

Comment: The stride calculation is correct, but accessing the individual bits of a single pixel would of course only work for a 32-bit RGBA format, which is not even supported by WPF. See [PixelFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats(v=vs.100).aspx) for a list of supported formats. What exactly are you trying to do with the raw pixel data?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to step through your code and figure out when `index` is larger than your `pixels` buffer size.

Add some debugging output to your code and step through it.  Something like:

```
if (source != null)
{
    int count = 0;

    int stride = (source.PixelWidth * source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    byte[] pixels = new byte[source.PixelHeight * stride];
    source.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

    for (int y = 0; y < source.PixelHeight; y = y + 2)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < source.PixelWidth; x = x + 2)
        {
            int index = y * stride + 4 * x;
            count = index;

            int bufsize = source.PixelHeight * stride;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"bufsize={bufsize}, index={index}, x={x}, y={y}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert((index+3) <= bufsize);

            byte red = pixels[index];
            byte green = pixels[index + 1];
            byte blue = pixels[index + 2];
            byte alpha = pixels[index + 3];
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Array Length, pixels: " + pixels.Count() + "," + count);
}
```

A big part about writing code is learning how to debug, use the debugger, and to verify the correctness of your algorithms.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

This code will crash on any image where `Format.BitsPerPixel` is less than 32 e.g. 24-bit RGB with no alpha. You also shouldn't assume that stride is what you think it is, you should use the value returned from LockBits.